# How to export a symbolic matrix to excel ?

Tags: excel, matlab

I want to calculate a matrix with symbolic entries and export the matrix to an excel file.

Approach:

```
syms x_1 y_1
A_sym = sym(zeros(2,2)); 
A_sym(1,1) = x_1; 
A_sym(2,1) = x_1 * y_1
A_sym(2,2) = y_1;
```

I tried to use the xlswrite('test.xls',A_sym,'A1:C5') function but it is somehow not designed for symbolic expressions and I get the following error:

> > Input data must be a numeric, cell, or logical array.

Afterwards I tried to typecast the content of my matrix to char and export it again:

```
 B = char(A); 
 xlswrite('test.xls',B,'A1:C5');
```

The result was that the function exported each character into a single excel cell which leads to the problem that the symbolic variables containing more than one char are not in one single excel cell but are divided into many cells which is useless for my purposes.

I guess there must be a better solution to export the variables into a single cell.

Does someone has a good solution ?

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is an output based on text, then you are on the right trach, but you need to do what you are doing *per matrix element*.

```
for ii=1:size(A_sym,1)
   for jj=1:size(A_sym,2)
      B{ii,jj}=char(A_sym(ii,jj));
   end
end

xlswrite('test.xls',B);
```

This will put a `char` version of the symbolic matrix with the same size in excel (in this case 2x2)